# adobe flash and flex , an alternative to ajax?

Tags: ajax, flash, apache-flex

There are many sites claming that adobe flash and flex can be used an an alternative to ajax.
Is this true. Flash is used to display video content on a web page right?
How can it be usd to replace ajax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javacript/ajax are conceptually very similar to ActionScript/Flash. (ActionScript is the Flex programming language.)

Actionscript is a strict superset of javascript with a bunch of extra capabilties and extra features for making people who like early-binding languages comfortable. (Like declaring variable types.)

Instead of running in the js virtual machine in your browser, like javascript, it runs in the VM in Flash.

Instead of using ajax to interact asynchronously with a host in the background, Adobe has its own very similar capabilities.

It was all really handy before javascript/ajax bulked out. And it has the portable AIR VM libraries for Windows, iOS, and linux, so it can run without being hosted in a browser.

Adobe is deemphasizing this technology though because they have seen that the future is HTML 5.

Example press hyperbole: 
http://www.pcworld.com/businesscenter/article/243130/adobe_flash_vs_html5.html
http://www.zdnet.com/blog/networking/flash-is-dead-long-live-html5/1633

Answer (score 2):

> There are many sites claming that adobe flash and flex can be used an
>   an alternative to ajax. I this true.

Yes, this is true.  Flex is a UI Framework for Enterprise development; and it leverages the Flash runtimes to allow for easy deployment to multiple platforms--such as desktop browser based applications (targeting Flash Player), desktop applications (targeting Adobe AIR), and Native Mobile Applications (Using Mobile AIR).

> Flash is used to display video content on a web page right?

It can be; but it is not limited to that.  Saying that "Flash is used to display video content" is like saying "John Lennon was a musician" or "C++ can loop over a data structure."  While, both are true; but a greatly simplified and do not communicate the full breadth of capability.

> How can it be used to replace ajax?

Flex is UI Framework; so it offers UI Components built in ActionScript (AKA The Language of the Flash Player).  It has a mechanism for customizing the look and feel of applications.  It has a mechanism for communicating with backend servers.  It can help you build applications quicker, and give a more consistent experience across multiple deployments.

People I talk to say that Enterprise Applications built in HTML/JavaScript solutions take 2-5 times longer than Flex solutions do today.  That is most likely going to change over time as tooling and frameworks improve on the HTML/JavaScript side of things.

To really understand Flex better, you should read the [docs](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/documentation.html) or check out [Adobe's Flex in a Week video series](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/videotraining.html).

---

Hopefully that gave an explanation what Flex is.  Whether you would want to learn Flex today or not is open to interpretation.  In my humble opinion, browser based Flash Player development is going to go away.  Flex is not supported in many mobile browsers (iOS and Windows Metro being two prominent options); and that will diminish the benefit of building Flash applications that target the browser.

I do believe that AIR will continue to thrive; as it allows you to use Flex/ActionScript to build desktop applications and mobile native applications.  Adobe is using this same technology to build their Creative Suite touch tools, such as Photoshop Touch, so we can rest assured that AIR will not go away in the near term.  It is my expectation that AIR development will be much more niche than Flash Player development ever was, though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think anyone can answer this question as the differences between ajax and flash/flex are huge.

BUT since you asked.

Flash is an animation suite that can do anything from show video, to 2d/3d games, to entire websites. It can communicate with javascript and basically any type of external program with the proper setup.

ajax refers to "asynchronous javascript and xml". So really it's just a bunch of techniques used in websites to let javascript talk asynchronously with a webserver.

So really flash can do everything that ajax does.. but you'll still need javascript and really flash is probably overkill for what you need. There's a lot of overhead with flash and it's real strength is with all things visual. With HTML5 javascript has caught up a bunch and so even if you just have something simple to show, html5 may be the way to go.

If you're not doing anything visual, flash/ajax is probably not what you're looking for. Especially because it wont work on most mobile devices.

Comment: Why would you "still need Javascript" for Flash development?

Comment: Depends on how you plan on using flash/ajax. If you're just replacing the ajax part of your website you'll need javascript to communicate with your flash swf and pass information from it to the rest of your website and such.
But if you replace all the dynamic pieces of your website with flash then it could obviously run standalone.